# Make RecyclerView "transparent" for touch

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, touch

I have the `RecyclerView`. I want scroll it like `ViewPager` with `TabLayout` and tabs (I've made this). I DON'T want to scroll it by my or other user's fingers, noses, elbows or else. But i want to user or me can use the same fingers, noses or elbows to interact with `itemView` of `viewHolder` of this `RecyclerView`. There is horizontal `LinearLayoutManager` attached to `RecyclerView` and there is vertical orientation `ScrollView` inside each of `itemView`. I want to make user can scroll `ScrollView` vertically, but if his finger by something reason go to left or right - `RecyclerView` scroll must not react.

I can add override of method `canScrollHorizontally` of `LayoutManager`, but it breaks horizontal scroll at all - even I select tabs.

I can add intercepting touch listener to recycler childs, which will call `recycler.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)`, but it works while child can scroll, as soon as it cant (finger goes to left or right) touch passes to `RecyclerView` and i get horizontall scroll.

How can i make RecyclerView fully "transparent" for touch?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way i've found - overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent`

```
public class TouchTransparentRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    public TouchTransparentRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TouchTransparentRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TouchTransparentRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        View childViewUnder = findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childViewUnder instanceof ViewGroup)
            return ((ViewGroup) childViewUnder).onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
        else
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
    }
}
```